# Rename sheets based on lookup table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to this so forgive me if I don't post this correctly.

I have a Excel file which contains various sheets, some of which are named V1, V2, ... up to a potential max of `V15`.

I have a table in 'Sheet names' cells `B2:C16`:
Column B contains the current sheet names `V1-V15`.
Column C contains the new sheet names/labels.

Are you able to offer some VBA code to be able to rename the sheets currently called V1 up to a potential max of V15 to the new values?

I've found quite a bit of stuff based on naming sheets from a list, but not in a vlookup style.

```
Sub RenSheets()  
Dim i As Integer  
For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count  
    Sheets(i).Name = Sheets("Sheet names").Range("C" & 2 + i)  
Next i  
End Sub
```

Thanks very much

Comment: This is not a code-generator service, show us what you have build or found yourself so far

Comment: Sorry, I'm stil learning VBA so pretty much finding everything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd look at starting it. Instead of looping through the worksheets and then trying to find the answer in your table, If you loop through the table and select the sheets (you can change the table location and size by modifying the `set rng` statement) This will then rename all of the worksheets that are detailed in that range.

```
Sub RenSheets()  
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim c

    set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet names").Range("B2:B16")

    For each c in rng.cells  
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(c.value).Name = c.offset(0,1).value  
    Next c  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try to not use `Sheets(i).Name`... if the sheet-order changed, you may get trouble

```
Sub RenSheets()
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 2 To 16 'Your Range = B2:C16
    Sheets(Sheets("Sheet names").Cells(i, 2)).Name = _ 'sheet to rename
    Sheets("Sheet names").Cells(i, 3) 'new sheetname
  Next
End Sub
```